# Anonymouse users can't see Openlayers Data Overlay

Tags: javascript

I have a map view displaying the Openlayers Data Overlay. It's displaying a list of GPS tracks from a "Map Feature" content type I made.

Logged in with the Administrator, I can see all the tracks on the map fine. The preview for the Data Overlay shows all the data coming through great.

When I few the map as an Anonymous user, not logged in, none of the GPS tracks show up. The map displays on the page but none of the data from my Data Overlay.

I've looked all over the place trying to find content permissions that are wrong that are screwing things up but I can't find anything.

Why is the data on the map showing for the administrator and not Anonymous users?

Comment: your other question might be related/ result of the same problem: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/102874/13366

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pages were cached for anonymous users. I went into Performance -> Caching  and cleared the caches and it worked. I had cleared my own cache but not on the site.