# Anonymous users can't see new content type in feed

Tags: views, users

I've made a new content type, and I've made a View that is a list of that new content type. Anonymous users don't get any content in that list but can see the individual content types. Admin users can see the content in the view fine. Is it a permissions issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possible problems. First of, dealing with unpublished content - assuming you created a content type with unpublished option as default, you will have to make sure that you tick the publish option on save/ create of new items. As per default registered and anonymous users can't see unpublished content.

Going further there could also be a problem inside of your view. You can manage access for the view itself in the middle column of the views ui edit page. There might also be a filter to only show published / published or admin items only.

[image]

also make sure that anonymous user can see content at all: `/admin/people/permissions`

[image]

Comment: Except if any of the above was the issue, the anonymous user would not be able to see the individual content nodes as indicated in the question.